# EntityFramework EntityType from ObjectContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, objectcontext

I have a method with this signature:

`public void GenerateLog<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : EntityObject`

How can I loop through my ObjectContext and call this for each Entity in my ObjectContext?
I know that I can do this:

```
foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in
                context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified))
{
    string entityName = entry.Entity.GetType().Name;
}
```

But I don't know how to go from a String representation of the name to `GenerateLog<MYSTRING>` instead of `GenerateLog<TEntity>`.

Comment: There's no way to call a generic method with a string, you'd have to provide an overload that just takes object (or some other common base class). What exactly does GenerateLog do internally? In other words, why is it generic to begin with? What do you do in the body of the method that there is value in it being a generic method? Perhaps with that knowledge people could provide an alternative solution or suggestion on how to accomplish what you want.

Comment: It is a method that logs changes against records in the database.  The TEntity filters down through the entire thing.  The whole thing is working wonderfully...except I am hung up on this point.  If I call it by providing an actual object type like GenerateLog<Contact> it works flawlessly.  But I need to call this without doing that as there are TONS of objects I would have to call it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a generic method from your `GenerateLog` and then call that. I normally need to mess around a bit before I get something like this to work, but this should be close

```
MethodInfo generateLog = typeof(YourClass)
    .GetMethod("GenerateLog", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance );

MethodInfo genericGenerateLog = generateLog.MakeGenericMethod(entry.Entity.GetType());

genericGenerateLog.Invoke(this, new object[] { entry.Entity });
```

`YourClass` is simply the class the GenerateLog is in.

Comment: Holy hell....that is amazing.  So far it's working PERFECTLY!  I haven't checked your answer yet though because I'm not 100% sure it is my solution because I have to fix other errors first. :P    So far it looks PERFECT though.

Comment: Brilliant solution Steve.  Works great!

Comment: @James That was my reaction when I first used MakeGenericMethod, which wasn't too long ago. It's very handy. The trade off is that it's slower than if you had a giant case statement with strongly typed calls or something along those lines.

Answer (score -1):

As Drew Marsh said, there's no way to call a generic method with only the name of the generic Type argument. Because of that, I can only suggest what you may well judge to be a bit of a rubbish solution using runtime method resolution - although it would work...

Firstly, assign a dynamic variable inside the `foreach`, and call a private method named (e.g.) `CallGenerateLog()`:

```
foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in
                context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified))
{
    dynamic dynamicEntity = entry.Entity;

    CallGenerateLog(dynamicEntity);
}
```

...provide one overload of `CallGenerateLog()` for each of the Entity types you want to log, and have each one call your `GenerateLog()` method, e.g.:

```
private static void CallGenerateLog(User user)
{
    GenerateLog(user);
}

private static void CallGenerateLog(Customer customer)
{
    GenerateLog(customer);
}
```

...etc... and provide a catch-all overload which will satisfy the compiler and be called if an Entity type you don't have an explicit overload for is found.

```
private static void CallGenerateLog(object entity)
{
}
```

Problems with this include:

1. You need an overload of `CallGenerateLog()` for each Entity type, so if you add a new Entity type which you want to log you'll have to remember to add an overload for it (although you could address this with T4 templates)
2. There is some overhead to runtime method resolution, so you may have to profile how well the method performs and decide if it's going to cause you any problems.

Comment: Making a call for each Entity Type is exactly what I wanted to avoid.  What are these "T4 Templates" you speak of?

Comment: Fair enough, re: one call per Type - this is just the only way I can think of towards what you want to achieve. T4 templates are code-generation files - The Entity Framework uses them to generate its default and POCO entity class source code - you'd still be making one call per Type, but you could reduce the chances of you forgetting an overload as the code would be auto-generated.